# Sorting a stack using recursion and without using extra space

Tags: recursion, data-structures, stack

I am trying to write a code for sorting a stack without using extra space. It is logically correct but my output is completely random. Could someone point out my mistake?

```
void insertatsortstack(int element, stack<int> s){

    if(s.empty()==1 || element > s.top())
    {
        s.push(element);
        return;
    }

    int temp=s.top();
    s.pop();
    insertatsortstack(element,s);
    s.push(temp);
}

void sortstack(stack<int> s){
    if(s.size()>0){
        int element=s.top();
        s.pop();
        sortstack(s);
        insertatsortstack(element,s);
    }
}
```

Comment: The indentation seems to be also random, so it is hard to read… Have you tried Valgrind or so? If result is random, I suspect some memory corruption.

Comment: `it is logically correct but my output is completely random` ... isn't this a complete contradiction?  Do you really have a real world need to do this, or is this a homework problem?  My vote is to _not_ use the stack to sort.  Instead, pop into a data structure like an array, which is much easier to use for sorting.  Then, reload the stack afterwards.

Comment: when i made a dry run according to me its correct and yes its not a homework problem . I am solving question from gfg to learn in detail and make it useful for my upcoming placement

Comment: @user46562 I have made some edits to make it more readable. Can you accept those?

Comment: Okay good! Now, to the algorithm, the given part of your algorithm works fine. I have assumed the rest of the implementation without changing this part of the algorithm. And it works all fine. I would suggest you to check your implementation of the rest of the parts, specially, `stack<int>`. If there are flaws that you are experiencing, they could most probably be caused by this.

Comment: On a sidenote, you said that you implement this to not to use extra space, but I think you have failed. Because, since you are using recursion, you have ended up consuming a lot of space in the runtime stack...

Comment: Try writing down, *in English*, what you want your code to do. Step by step. Using a deck of cards or a stack of coins, simulate those steps by hand. *Then* write code to implement that solution on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are coming from the Java background. You are passing the value in functions which will make a copy of your stack and your original stack will not be changed. You need to pass value by the reference.

```
void insertatsortstack(int element, stack<int> & s);
void sortstack(stack<int> &s);
```

[Working Code Implementation](https://ideone.com/ce1H1R)

(Assuming that you are using std:: stack)

Answer (score -1):

#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void
insertatsortstack (int element, stack < int >&s)
{

if (s.empty () == 1 || element > s.top ())

```
{
```

s.push (element);

return;

}

int temp = s.top ();

s.pop ();

insertatsortstack (element, s);

s.push (temp);

}

void

sortstack (stack < int >&s)
{

if (s.size () > 0)
{

int element = s.top ();

s.pop ();

sortstack (s);

insertatsortstack (element, s);

}

}

int

main ()
{

stack < int >s;

s.push (5);

s.push (1);

s.push (4);

s.push (3);

s.push (6);

s.push (9);

s.push (2);

s.push (3);

s.push (8);

sortstack (s);

while (s.empty () == false)
{

cout << s.top () << " ";

s.pop ();

}

}

Comment: Please use proper formatting in your answer.

Comment: And don't recommend '#include<bits/stdc++.h>` in answers on Stack Overflow. [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/10871073)